# Search my code and throw exception from Powershell

Tags: powershell

How would I write a script that will search my code files for key phrases (like "fit(" in a jasmine unit test) and throw an exception if it finds one.  I don't mind supplying a top folder, but it should search through subfolders.  Bonus points if I can pass it the key phrases in an array.  I'm also ok with installing a node package to facilitate.

I have a script in my package json file I use for "checking in" files. It builds all, runs all tests, stages files and then commits them.  I'd like to add this at the beginning, and exit (not build -> test, etc) if a forbidden phrase is found. (debugging flags like fit, deprecated methods maybe).

```
"commit-all": "ng build core-library --prod && ng build --prod && echo Executing tests && ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless --no-watch --codeCoverage=false && git checkout tsconfig.json && git checkout src/environments/environment.ts && git add . && git commit -m "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string), and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlets as follows:

```
$dir = '...' # specify the directory whose subtree to search.
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -File -Filter *.ps1 | 
  Select-String 'fit(', 'fun(' -List | 
    ForEach-Object { Throw "Phrase found: $($_ | Out-String)" }
```

If you package the above as a script, using `Throw` will make your script report an exit code of `1`.

Alternatively, if you want to find and report *all* matches before reporting an error, omit the `ForEach-Object` call, collect all matches with `$matchesFound = Get-ChildItem ...` and throw with them, or use `Write-Error` and manually call `exit 1`.

To invoke the script via [the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), use:

```
# PowerShell [Core] executable shown; use powershell.exe for Windows PowerShell
pwsh -NoProfile -File YourScript.ps1
```

Note: Sadly, the PowerShell CLI unexpectedly reports errors via *stdout*, and errors messages are noisy and span multiple lines in Windows PowerShell - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669365/45375) for a workaround and background information.